# android sqlite database search without buttonclick

Tags: java, android

Anyone please solves my problem. I'm created a database (SQLite) with 4 columns i.e.

```
|-----|------|---------|--------|
|  ID | NAME | CODE    | AGE    |
|-----|------|---------|--------|
|-----|------|---------|--------|
```

My activity is to retrieve name from database and display in textview when enter the code in edittext. Not using button click.

```
|EditText|        |Textview |
```

if name-jim
code-1200
age-38
when i enter 1200(code) in EditText then display jim(name) in Textview sametime.

Please help me to write a simple method
Thank you

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  SO is not a code writing service.  You need to show some effort. What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please have a look to [How do I ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)